# jBuilder ignore_nil! site wide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I'm working on a Rails API using jBuilder and want to exclude null from all my JSON objects.

jBuilder has the following method:

```
def ignore_nil!(value = true)
  @ignore_nil = value
end
```

How and where can I override this method to be true for everything? This would make much more sense and be more maintainable than going through every json view I have and adding it.

Answer (score 0):

JBuilder doesn't provide one place to specify `:ignore_nil` option. You can look at `JbuilderHandler` class in `jbuilder_template.rb` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else stumbles upon this:

`JBuilder.ignore_nil true`

will set the default value of `ignore_nil` to true everywhere.

You could (assuming you are using rails) just put this in an initializer.